# Can't get Stack Overflow avatar to stick

Tags: discussion, avatar

I've been trying to add an avatar here, but something is broken.

I first noticed the avatar that should be automatically pulled from my Google account doesn't work, and I figured that was because it was now [WebP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP), so I first made a local [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) version, tried to upload that, didn't work, then a win/OS2 bitmap, no dice.  Is there an update lag I have to wait on?

The previous question pointed to does not pertain to why images uploaded as files from the user's own machine might result in a broken avatar.

Comment: What is "OS2"? "[OS/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS/2)"? "win/OS2 bitmap" = [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)?

Comment: For now I would just upload the image in your profiles your self. When you edit your profile there is a change picture tab when you hover over your profile, with an upload options. That brings your image on the imgur instance SE is using.

Comment: That's just how my ancient Paint Shop Pro lists the bitmap formats it supports in the save dialog format selector,
ie

Windows or OS/2 Bitmap (*.bmp)
and
Windows or OS/2 DIB (*.dib)

Comment: I actually did that, first as a png file, then the windows format bitmap bmp.

Comment: This is where you upload and select your profile: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqG8Z.png . As evidenced by the current result you haven't selected the uploaded variant as it points to a google domain. So either adjust your setting here on your Stack Overflow profile to resolve the issue. For your case, given the current state, the duplicate is correct and it is not something you can fix by uploading images at Googles end.

Comment: Can't get an avatar to stick around? Oddly Disney Plus is having a similar conundrum.

Comment: rene, 

That 404'd google image currently still pointed to is just what was automatically attached by stackoverflow, not me, when I signed up via my google account.   Makes sense that the google avatar would be used by default, right?  But I certainly didn't set it.  My google account has a different avatar now at a different google url of similar server type https://lh3.googleusercontent.com...,, because I changed it via my google profile to something different   and I would think stackoverflow would simply update to that, but guess not.